# Postgres natural order by

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

I have a sorting issue in postgres in a column with values such as version.
Version is character varying, with values such as the following (un-ordered).

```
1.2
1.3
1.10.1
1.9
```

How do I sort in natural order such that when I issue `SELECT version FROM TABLE_A ORDER BY version DESC` it will give me

```
1.10.1
1.9
1.3
1.2
```

instead of

```
1.9
1.3
1.2
1.10.1
```

Comment: How many numbers your version code might have?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Postgres allow you to sort by arrays -- which is essentially what the version number represents.  Hence, you can use this syntax:

```
order by string_to_array(version, '.')::int[] desc
```

Here is a full example:

```
select *
from (values ('1'), ('2.1'), ('1.2.3'), ('1.10.6'), ('1.9.4')) v(version)
order by string_to_array(version, '.')::int[] desc;
```

And even a [demonstration](http://rextester.com/SGCK66899).

Comment: Thank you Gordon. I have to deal even with a worse set of data. But you hinted out the solution. `select *
from (values ('1'), ('2.1'), ('1.2.3'), ('1.10.6'), ('1.10.10'), ('1.10'), ('1.9.4') , ('1.9.BETA')) v(version)
order by string_to_array(regexp_replace(array_to_string(regexp_matches(version, '[\d|\.]+'), ''), '\.$', ''), '.')::int[] desc;`

Answer (score 0):

One way: (works if version may have maximum 3 parts)

```
with t(col) as(
    select '1.9' union all
    select '2' union all
    select '1.2' union all
    select '1.10.1'  
)
select * from t
order by 
case when split_part(col, '.', 1) = '' then 0 else split_part(col, '.', 1)::int end desc, 
case when split_part(col, '.', 2) = '' then 0 else split_part(col, '.', 2)::int end desc, 
case when split_part(col, '.', 3) = '' then 0 else split_part(col, '.', 3)::int end desc
```