# How to calculate the max of a version kind of field in postgresql?

Tags: amazon-redshift, aggregates

I have a table like this:

```
Category    Version
B   1.8.11
B   1.20.138
B   1.29.01
B   1.30.89
B   1.3.114
```

Now, I want to get the latest version. 
By default, order by doesn't work because 1.8.11 is treated the highest.

I understand one way is to use split_part and substring and get the latest version which in this case will be 1.30.89.

Just wanted to understand if there is a better way to achieve this.

**Edit1:**

I am using redshift postgresql.So, not all postgresql functions are available.

Another way I figured out yet is something like this. Herein I pad zeroes to the left and then I have to remove them before reporting the actual version.

```
(TO_CHAR(SPLIT_PART(version,'.',1),'fm000') + '.' + TO_CHAR(SPLIT_PART(version,'.',2),'fm000') + '.' + TO_CHAR((case when SPLIT_PART(version,'.',3) = '' then '0' else SPLIT_PART(version,'.',3) end),'fm000')) AS padded_version
```

**EDIT2:**
I got a slightly better method. So, just sharing it here:

```
select category, version from
(SELECT CATEGORY,
             VERSION,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CATEGORY ORDER BY SPLIT_PART(VERSION,'.',1)::INT DESC,SPLIT_PART(VERSION,'.',2)::INT DESC),SPLIT_PART(VERSION,'.',3)::INT DESC)
from table1)
where row_number = 1
```

Thanks!

Comment: I saw it answered on SO...

Comment: eg https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/74298/30035

Comment: or https://stackoverflow.com/a/30773470/5315974

Comment: or https://stackoverflow.com/a/43897730/5315974

Comment: @VaoTsun Thanks for redirecting me to that question. I got to know something new. But unfortunately, I am using redshift's version of postgresql and it doesn't really support string_to_array operation. Is there any other workaround?

Comment: ah redshiiift. then I suppose you way is good enough, o course it is limitedto n dots and so on. but I wont be able to help here, as I know nothing about redshift

Comment: This is NOT a duplicate question. please un-mark it as one

Comment: You could use a python UDF to normalise the string into something that is more sortable. that approach gives you a bit more control than your current method (if you need it)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @JonScott. For the time being I could do it using the split_part as mentioned in Edit2. But I will try python UPF as well. :)